# Create curved meshes without using Paths?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've been looking at tutorials on how to create a curved object and all they all use paths. I'm trying to create a curved building. How can I create a tangible 3D curved mesh that doesn't involve stacking slightly rotated objects onto one another, Like a path would do?

Comment: Is it possible you could give an example of what you mean by "curved"?

Comment: what do you mean by curved??

Comment: Use the curve modifier

Comment: Some sort of image reference would be invaluable

Comment: I guess you would have to manually model it.

Comment: maybe this will help too: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Curve_Tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this may not be pleasing to hear, but there are two ways to do this.

- **The hard way** (manually model the object to be curved)
- **The easy way** (it requires using a *curve* modifier.)

Since the first way really requires step by step or a tutorial, and is out of scope for this site, I'll give you the easy way.

### Using a *Curve* modifier

Create your object that you want to curve, make it the length that you want it to be. Be sure it has plenty of vertical subdivisions or edge loops, the more, the merrier. (actually, just the smoother after curving.) This picture shows the mesh properly set up to be curved, notice the "up-down" lines, these are the loops I was talking about.

[image]

I know you didn't want to use curves, but **Create a curve!** in order to get something really nice without a lot of trouble, you need curves, and once you get used to them, they really aren't that bad.

Once you've shaped the curve *just* right you can re-select the mesh and add a curve modifier. isert the curve you just created under the **Object** parameter.

[image]

Very good! you now have a curved object: if it hangs off the edge of the curve a little, just mess with the location of the mesh.

Comment: He said he doesn't want to use a curve.

Comment: He said he didn't want to use a curve that stacked them. if he doesn't want to do it the easy way, this question is off-topic as it is a tutorial request. this was the question line *How can I create a tangible 3d curved mesh that doesn't involve stacking slightly rotated objects onto one another, Like a path would do?*

Comment: @PGmath if you read the edit history his original post did not contain "I don't want to use curves."

Comment: Than you, on all the tutorials i watched none of them explained how to apply the curve to objects

Comment: @sudoadmin No problem.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a simple deformation, like twisting or bending, you could just use the [*simple deform* modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Simple_Deform) set to *twist* or *bend*.  No need for curves or anything complicated!

Simple deform works by deforming the object's bounding box, you can read the linked wiki for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Screw* modifier. For this all you need to do is make a two dimensional profile of the curved object you want to make:

[image]

You can then add the modifier:
[image]

Your mesh will now look like this:
[image]

Notice that the *Angle* setting decides over how large of an arc the mesh is screwed.

You can change the radius by simply moving the vertices (in *Edit* mode) farther from the origin.