# Unwrap Curved Flat Stripe

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv

How to unwrap this curved flat surface? [image: curved flat stripe]

How to unwrap such mesh properly? I want to fix texture mapping on the curved part of the mesh. My plan is to make smth like river animation(U coordinate animation).

Wireframe and texture:
[image: blended]

Thank you!

Comment: go to top view, press **U** and select **project from view**

Comment: He wants to animate the UVs to look like a river. So the UV island after unwrapping have to be horizontal (as shown on a picture above), not curved. I think the 'project from view' is not a good solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start with a shape like this and unwrap it.

[image]

then add an array modifier and a curve modifier to control the array.

[image]

Blend file **[here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33805)**

Comment: Big thank you for the help! Exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: For help with curve mod, see [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23101/create-curved-meshes-without-using-paths/23103#23103) answer.