# UV Mapping a spinned object

Tags: texturing, uv, normal-map

So I'm creating roads for my game.
When I create 90 degrees turns with the Spin tool, the road spin perfectly and everything, the only thing is that the texture gets stretched out, and I was wondering how I could fix it by saving time. I know how to fix it if I take 2 verticies and straighten them up and doing this with all the others, but I was wondering if I could save time by doing this.

Here is where I want to start the UV mapping :

[image: screenshot-uv-mapping]
http://prntscr.com/fesnhl

Any short-cuts or anything I could use to do this fast and easy ?

Comment: Please use built-in possibility to insert images. As to UV map either UVSquares or QuadUnwrap addons should do it fast (not to mention you could do it manually).

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65565/straighten-the-series-of-vertices-in-uv-editor

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23133/unwrap-curved-flat-stripe/23134#23134